# launch a batch remote command via /putty ssh and get the output in a local file

Tags: putty

I have been trying to launch a remote command in putty using the -m [file] flag and get the output 
`putty.exe -[user]@server -m commandscript` 
(the command is just `cat> somewhere` ) and after that I just get the output file via scp.
Well it is not working for whatever reason but my question is:
Can I get the output of a remote putty command just using the putty enviroment (without getting the file via scp??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish that with plink, which is available at [PuTTY download page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).

Example:

```
plink user@server "cat /tmp/some/file" > local_output.txt
```

Comment: perfect, I thought plink was just for the tunnelling sessions. Muchas gracias!